# Is it possible to retrive in one file bash's history commands?

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I have a lot a commands that I want to run again, but there are a lot of them, and going up to them with the up arrow key is too long. Is it possible to get it in a cat/tail command and pipe it to a file ?

Comment: You don't need the up arrow. You can also just type Ctrl-r and then start typing one of your previous commands. Then type Ctrl-r repeatedly to cycle through a list of commands that match.

Comment: It is stored in `~/.bash_history`

See also  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168676/bash-history-does-it-always-record-every-command-i-ever-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the history command:

```
history > my_file
```

Comment: FYI, the `history` command will output the contents of the `.bash_history` file, plus recently executed commands not yet stored in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Type Ctrl-R and then type the first few letters of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to ~/.inputrc would make the up and down arrows cycle through commands that match the start of the line:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

I also use these functions a lot:

```
h() {
    if [ $# = 0 ]; then
        history 33 | sed '$d'
    else
        history | grep -iEF "$*" | grep -v '^ *[0-9]* *h '
    fi
}

r() {
    history ${1-200} | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* *//' | tail -r > /tmp/recent
    open /tmp/recent -e
}
```

If you add `" ": magic-space` to .inputrc, you can insert command 1234 by typing `!1234` and a space. But it also makes space stop work in irb and the interactive mode in gnuplot.

Comment: Very interesting !